# How can I pass a string from one method to another using TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

In my tests I am to capture a string in one method and then later use it in a different method. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
public class stackOverflowExample {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static Properties OR = null;

@Test
public void test_1() throws InterruptedException {

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\iedriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");               
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();


 driver.get("http://www.google.com");

Thread.sleep(1500);

String string1 = driver.findElement(By.id("btnK")).getText();

System.out.println(string1);

}

public void test_2() {

  System.out.println(string1);


}
}
```

How can I use string1 in the test_2() method?

*Edit:

For clarity of why I am trying to do this, I am running a test that does the following:

1. Logs into website under User1
2. Creates a new mortgage application
3. Logs out of User1, then logs back in under User2
4. User2 would then open up the newly created mortgage application and run various test scenarios.

Comment: Make it global in class?

Comment: I apologize for my limited knowledge in this area. I'm quite new to this. How would I go about making it global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it:

```
public class SomeTest {

    public static String string1 = null; // It's a global String

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        string1 = "blabla"; // Change value for global String
        System.out.println(string1); // Print value of global String
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println(string1); // Print value of global String
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you are trying to do is discouraged. Unit tests are meant to be independent of each.

Also afaik, there is no strict ordering that follows when tests are being executed. What I mean by this is that, test_2() could actually be tested before test_1() and hence string1 is not available to test_2() anyways. Tests can also be run parallelly.

The correct way to do it, IMO is to make the call that gets string1 in test_2() as well... If you think this step of obtaining string1 is required for every test in the class, consider using @Before annotation for a setup() which is a function that is executed before all the tests and storing string1 in class level variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I rushed to get this example written. I normally have a "Master" method that runs the different methods in order that they are written. For example, the Master method would say: 

    public void master() { 

    test_1();
    test_2();
    }